# How to solve this linear system in Matlab?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, matlab

I'm trying to solve the following linear system and I'd like to do it via software to make sure the answer is correct.

[image: linear system]

I'm looking for the transfer functions $\dfrac{i_L(s)}{d(s)}$ and $\dfrac{v_o(s)}{i_L(s)}$.

Comment: Do you have the [Symbolic Math Toolbox](https://www.mathworks.com/products/symbolic.html)?

Comment: Sim, eu tenho @RodrigodeAzevedo

Comment: Then create symbol `s` and symbols `R`, `D`, `L`, etc. Create the symbolic matrix and the symbolic vector. Make $v_{in}=0$. Left-multiply both sides by the inverse of the symbolic matrix. You will obtain a vector of three transfer functions.

Comment: Why $v_{in}$ is equal to zero ?

Comment: Because you seem to want only the transfer functions from the disturbance $d$. Note that the product of the two transfer functions you want is the transfer function from $d$ to $v_o$.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo the "s" is from Laplace, should I have to create the symbol s too ? I Really don't have how to solve this :( and I need it urgently to a technical report

Comment: What data do you have? Do you have the values of the resistances and capacitances? If that is the case, you only need to create one symbol, namely, `s`. If you want the transfer functions as a function of the resistances and capacitances, then you must create more symbols.